# c# использование datagridview без SQL с относительно большим количеством данных без проседания скорости

Tags: c#, datagridview

Интересует использование datagridview **без SQL** с относительно большим количеством данных **без проседания скорости**.

Если добавлять элементы напрямую в датагрид -- это занимает довольно много времени. Что не удивительно, ведь вью не предназначенное для работы с данными. Оно предназначенное для показа. 
В моей таблице с которой мне нужно работать в программе 19~ колонок (в том числе чекбокс) и может быть больше 40 000 строк.
Заметно тормозит юай самого три вью при скролинге даже при каких-то паре тысяч строк если добавлять данные напрямую в него.

Я НЕ хочу использовать SQL. Ни в каком виде. В том числе и SQLite.

**Итак сам вопрос:**

**Как правильно работать с три вью не используя SQL и без проседания по скорости?**
Если есть ссылки на статьи -- тоже сгодится.

Comment: [Виртуальный режим](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/15a31akc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Уточните вопрос: версия фреймворка, технология, какие данные подгружаете? Реализуют ли ваши объекты INPC? Если да, то каков способ реализации. Судя по описанию, даже если вы и использовали бы SQL, на наличие тормозов при отрисовке, это не повлияло бы. Не совсем понятна суть вопроса. Опять же. Вначале вопроса вы говорите о datagrid, в конце - о treeview. Так с каким именно элементом проблема? Ну и, конечно же, пример вашего кода — в студию.

Comment: Не вижу вообще где ты увидел treeview. Всюду про datagridView. Но парень выше правильно подсказал причину тормозов)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov запость линку ответом, отмечу как правильный ответ. Спасибо за подсказку! Раньше не сталкивался с виртуальным режимом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказал Alexander Petrov - решением является виртуальный режим.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/15a31akc(v=vs.110).aspx

Спасибо ему большое.