# Что такое SharedRow в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Читал некоторые статьи на тему увеличения производительности и наткнулся на фразу, что строка может быть Shared, но так и не понял что это и зачем. С кем ей можно делиться и влияет ли она в итоге на скорость работы DataGridView.

Comment: это вроде как шаринг строк между несколькими ДатаГридВью. Даже не догадываюсь для чего это может понадобится. На скорость работы влияет в первую очередь способ подгрузки данных. Данные могут быть как подгружены полностью все - так и только необходимые что делается через виртуальный режим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/555700/186752

Comment: [Здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#using-shared-rows) описано. Кратко: Shared rows экономят память.

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA виртуальный режим уже использую, спасибо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov именно здесь и нашёл упоминание. надо было почитать внимательнее первую фразу - Efficient memory use is achieved in the DataGridView control through shared rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared row - способ сэкономить память. Одна строка может использоваться сразу в нескольких местах, избегая дубликатов. При этом она старается не дублировать максимально много информации о своём использовании.

> Rows will share as much information about their appearance and behavior as possible

Кроме уменьшенного потребления памяти, других упоминаний влияния на производительность не найдено.

Больше можно прочитать [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#using-shared-rows).

Comment: Я это понял так: например, к гриду привязана коллекция с тысячей строк, а размер грида задан таким, что видно только десять строк. Вот для этих десяти строк и создаются Shared rows. Когда мы прокручиваем грид, например, вниз, то одна строка уползает вверх, становится невидимой, после чего отсоединятеся и она же присоединяется снизу.